# Elementary iOS: How to enable visualextra in vim 7.4

Tags: ubuntu, vim, terminal

I miss the visual block mode in my vim 7.4 instance. I checked `echo has('visualextra')` and obtained `1`, so I have the functionality. How do I enable it?

Comment: What does this has to do with iOS? If your system conflicts with ^V, used for something else, you can always go with to visual block mode with ^Q. This has been asked many times, and is also in the Vim docs under the CTRL-V topic.

Comment: ^Q doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl-V` to enable the visual block mode . And  press `J` several times to expand your selection. Then  press `Shift-I` to insert, place your text, and when you press Esc, it has only modified the top line of the selection.

Comment: When I press `CTRL-V`, it pastes the content of the clipboard to the beginning of the current line.

Comment: @TMOTTM  To paste the clipboard content 'V' but to enable visual block mode 'ctrl-v'

Comment: What do you mean? Of course I'm entering "Control-Vee", but then immediately the clipboard is pasted.

Comment: what happen when you press only V

Comment: It enters visual mode, but then I can select only full lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138410/discussion-between-ankur-jyoti-phukan-and-tmottm).

Comment: @TMOTTM try shift-V  i think someone had change the key mapping for vim ..